# Trigger event on page change

Tags: reactjs, material-table

With material-table component, how can I trigger an event when the page changes? I want to do this, because I want to keep the page number to restore the state.

```
import MaterialTable from 'material-table';

...

render() {
    return (
        <div style={{ maxWidth: "100%" }}>
        <MaterialTable
            icons={tableIcons}
            options={
            {
                exportButton: true,
                exportAllData: true,
                selection: false,
                filtering: true,
                pageSize: 10,
                pageSizeOptions: [5, 10, 25]
            }
            }
            columns={columns}
            data={tableData}
            title={title}
        />
        </div>
    );
    }
```

Comment: Where are you storing the page number? Are you using redux or passing through query params?

Comment: I would just keep it in the parent state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `onChangePage`. It's a props of `MaterialTable`.

[Material Table All Props](https://material-table.com/#/docs/all-props)

Comment: Would you also happen to know how to pass the current page (so I can start at page 3 when restoring a state for example)? I can't seem to find it in the props.

Comment: Why, that's easy. It's `initialPage`.